# Building Many-to-many query with EF

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using EF5 with .net 4.0 and I have 3 entities - User, Project and Interest. I connected User *Many2Many* Interest and Project *Many2Many* Interest using FluentAPI (it created additional 2 tables for each relation). Everything works great.

What I want to do is to load all projects per user who has same interests. I tried

```
Project ... 
  .Where(p => p.Interests
               .Any(t => user.Interests.All(i => i.Url == t.Url)));
```

(Interest has PK Url). When I perform this query, I get error

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'DAL.Models.Interest'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

What is the right query?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want the query to return?  You want all the projects in your context that shares any interest with a particular user?

Comment: Yes, that is my desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you can't translate user.Interests.All(...) into a SQL procedure.

You can however, create a list of the primitive type (Url) and then compare against that.

```
        var userInterests = user.Interests.Select(u => u.Url);
        var sharedProjects = m.Projects.Where( p => p.Interests.Select(i => i.Url)
                   .Any(pi => userInterests.Any(ui => ui == pi)));
```